# How to get sum of column in same table then difference between 2 table using sql

Tags: mysql

How have two tables

1.doner_record-->

```
Id| doner_id|blood_group | units |status|
1 |       1       |A                    | 3        |0         |
2 |        3      |B                    | 2        |0         |
3 |        2      |A                    | 1        |0         |
4 |        1      |A                    | 2        |0         |
```

2 . acceptors

```
Id| name        |blood_group | units |status|
1 |       ayush  |A                    | 1        |0         |
2 |       akash  |B                    | 2        |0         |
3 |        Hari     |A                   | 1        |0         |
4 |        Ram    |A                   | 1        |0         |
```

How can I get  stocks of blood group using sql

```
|blood_group | units |
|A                    | 3        |
|B                    | 0        |
```

Answer (score 0):

For Stocked Unit of Blood, you need to check the left unit from the accepted sum of the unit.

**Check this query may this get you the result:**

```
select blood_group,(ifnull(t1.unit,0) - ifnull(t2.unit,0)) as StockedUnit  from 
(select blood_group,sum(unit) unit from 
doner_record group by blood_group) t1
left outer join
(select blood_group,sum(unit) unit from 
acceptors group by blood_group) t2

on t1.blood_group = t2.blood_group
```